# How to fly the step-down fixes on the LOC 32 approach at Dothan (KDHN)?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, approach, iaps

From Oaldy to CABTA is 2600, then is it CABTA to KENSY down to 2200? Using Localizer only...I see the glideslope intercept says 2200 but Kensy is father up.

[image: ILS or LOC RWY 32 at KDHN]

Comment: What do you mean by "KENSY is farther up"?  Are you looking at the 6K' on the profile view?

Answer (score 1):

If you’re flying the LOC, the GSIP (lightning bolt) is irrelevant.

- OALDY to CABTA is at or above 2600
- CABTA itself is at or below 6000
- CABTA to KENSY is at or above 2200
- KENSY is the FAF, and then you can descend to the MDA of 1220
- If you can identify FEKRA, you can descend to a new MDA of 720

Answer (score 1):

That approach plate can be a bit confusing at first.

If you fly a straight in LOC approach via IAF OADLY you assumed correctly that you need to be at 2600ft or above until CABTA and then you can descent to 2200ft or above until KENSY. Those published altitudes are considered minimum altitudes.

At KENSY you are going to start your final descent and you'll be a little bit (33ft) above a 3° profile. You can deduct that from 2167ft crossing height at KENSY published for the ILS version for this approach.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Kensy is father up" in your question but I have the suspicion that you got confused by the profile view. Keep in mind that the profile view visualises the procedure turn portion of the approach with KENSY as IAF. These altitudes (up to crossing KENSY again) are not applicable for your straight in approach via OADLY.